# SOLR 4.3 on Ubuntu 12.04LTS - conf directory missing when creating SOLR cores

Tags: solr, solr4

I've been fighting a long battle with SOLR, trying to get it running properly.
I finally have SOLR running (multicore) on Tomcat7.
In the SOLR admin area I can see the cores.

Originally when I tired to create a new core, I would always get errors indicating that solrconfig.xml could not be found. I solved that by copying solrconfig.xml and schema.xml to the tomcat/lib folder so that the files are in the classpath. Might not be the best solution, but it worked.  I can now create new cores, but when I do, the conf directory (and it's contents) are not created in the new core directory. The core directory itself IS created, and the data dir is created.

Also, the solr.xml file is not modified, so the new core doesn't persist once solr is restarted.

Any suggestions as to why the conf directory isn't created, and why the solr.xml file isn't modified for the new core?

I'll be happy to provide more information as required.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: Update: I've also tried a multicore install of SOLR on Windows (tomcat7) and I'm having the same problem there. SOLR itself seems to be working, but I cannot properly create new cores.  I wonder if something needs to be changed in the solrconfig.xml template or somewhere else. When adding a new core, I would think the system should modify solr.xml and create "conf" ...